# Efficiency of particle accelerators

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, collision, accelerator-physics

Say the SLAC linear accelerator, to perform inelastic scattering, wants to fire an electron accelerated to 0.99c the speed of light at targets of atomic nuclei.
After the collision, the resulting total energy output, including the binding energy of the target proton, was around 0.1 TEV.

However, the efficiency of a system is given by

$$η = \frac{E_{out}}{E_{in}}$$

Therefore, to find the efficiency we need to figure out the total energy input. Hence, my questions are:

i) Including energy required accelerate the particles as well as the energy required for the electromagnetic fields, what would be the total energy input?

ii) How efficient would the particle accelerator be?

Comment: What do you define as Pin? The total power required by the facility that includes cooling, power for magnets etc? That is probably a multiple of what goes into the klystrons that power the actual accelerator. Klystron efficiency is typically around 50%, I believe. Superconducting resonator losses have to be negligible, otherwise the cooling would fail quickly. And then there is the question of Pout... which is vastly different in a storage ring than in a Linac because of Bremsstrahlung losses.

Comment: Particle accelerators are not efficient at all. Magnets to keep the beam focused are incredibly wasteful beasts.

Answer (score 1):

The overall "efficiency" of SLAC was very, very small. Fortunately, its scientific objectives did not require it to be efficient. It met its objectives, while throwing away a lot of energy. Nobel prizes were produced.